# Message files not being generated properly with catkin_make

Tags: c++, catkin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a workspace with 3 packages: an rqt plugin written in C++ (package A), a package with two custom messages (package B), and another C++ package (package C).

Packages A and C both rely on the custom messages defined in package B. To ensure that the dependencies for the executables in packages A and C are met, I have added the following line for each applicable executable:

`add_dependencies(executable_name ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})`

Unfortunately, when I try to compile using `catkin_make`, I get an error saying that the header file for the messages don't exist. I'm fairly certain this error is coming from package A, the rqt plugin, since doing a catkin_make on package C alone generates no errors and successfully compiles the header files for the messages before trying to compile the executables (and catkin_make on the entire workspace works just fine after that since the header files have already been generated).

How do I go about telling catkin that the rqt plugin depends on the message files? I already have the message package name listed in the CMakeLists.txt file for the plugin as `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS package_b)` but that doesn't resolve the issue.

I'm currently compiling in ROS Kinetic but this issue existed in Indigo as well before I upgraded.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

***Update*:

**CMakeLists.txt files**

Package A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rqt_gcs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
            query_msgs
            geometry_msgs
            mavros
            mavros_msgs
            roscpp
            rqt_gui
            rqt_gui_cpp
            roslib
            sensor_msgs
            std_msgs
            tf
            cv_bridge
            image_transport
)

find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtSvg REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include(${QT_USE_FILE})
include(EnableCXX11)
include(MavrosMavlink)

set(rqt_gcs_SRCS
  src/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.cpp
  src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp
  src/FIS/qfi_PFD.cpp
  src/FIW/LayoutSquare.cpp
  src/FIW/WidgetPFD.cpp
  src/rqt_image_view/ratio_layouted_frame.cpp
)

set(rqt_gcs_HDRS
  include/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.h
  include/FIS/qfi_PFD.h
  include/FIW/LayoutSquare.h
  include/FIW/WidgetPFD.h
  include/rqt_image_view/ratio_layouted_frame.h
)

set(rqt_gcs_UIS
  resources/gcs.ui
  resources/AccessPointsMenu.ui
  resources/AccessPointStats.ui
  resources/MissionSelect.ui
  resources/MissionCancel.ui
  resources/MissionProgress.ui
  resources/UavStat.ui
  resources/UavQuestion.ui
  resources/QuadStats.ui
  resources/WidgetPFD.ui
  resources/PFDWidget_custom.ui
  resources/WidgetMain.ui
  resources/UAVCondition.ui
  resources/ImageView.ui
  resources/MissionConfirm.ui
  resources/PictureMsg.ui
)

SET(rqt_gcs_RCCS resources/qfi.qrc)

set(rqt_gcs_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
  include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ${rqt_gcs_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rqt_gui rqt_gui_cpp std_msgs sensor_msgs
)

include_directories(include
    ${Qt4_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_definitions(${Qt4_DEFINITIONS})


qt4_add_resources(rqt_gcs_RCC_SRCS ${rqt_gcs_RCCS})
qt4_wrap_cpp(rqt_gcs_MOCS ${rqt_gcs_HDRS})
qt4_wrap_ui(rqt_gcs_UIS_H ${rqt_gcs_UIS})

include_directories(${rqt_gcs_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
                    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Declare executables with source files
add_executable(simple_control src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp)
add_executable(gps_publisher src/rqt_gcs/gps_publisher.cpp)
add_executable(gps_demo src/rqt_gcs/gps_demo.cpp)
add_executable(connection_manager src/rqt_gcs/connection_manager.cpp)
add_executable(safe_mocap src/rqt_gcs/safe_mocap.cpp)

add_dependencies(simple_control ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(gps_demo ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
            ${rqt_gcs_SRCS}
            ${rqt_gcs_MOCS}
            ${rqt_gcs_UIS_H}
            ${rqt_gcs_RCC_SRCS})

#Specify libraries against which to link
target_link_libraries(simple_control ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(gps_publisher ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(gps_demo ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(connection_manager ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(safe_mocap ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(  ${PROJECT_NAME}
                        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                        ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
                        ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}
                        ${QT_QTSVG_LIBRARY}
                        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)

find_package(class_loader)
class_loader_hide_library_symbols(${PROJECT_NAME})

install(FILES plugin.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/rqt_gcs
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
install(PROGRAMS scripts/rqt_gcs
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)
```

Package B:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(query_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation
                                        sensor_msgs
                                        geometry_msgs)

include_directories(include)

add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY msg
  FILES
  Door.msg
  Target.msg)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs geometry_msgs)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime sensor_msgs geometry_msgs)
```

---

**Package.xml files**

Package A:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>rqt_gcs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The rqt_gcs package</description>

  <maintainer email="hovig@todo.todo">hovig</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>



  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rqt_gui</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rqt_gui_cpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>mav_control</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>query_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rqt_gui</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rqt_gui_cpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rostopic</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>mav_control</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>query_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>
    <rqt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

Package B:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>query_msgs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The query_msgs package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="serl@todo.todo">serl</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>
    <architecture_independent/>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

**The compile output** (Error is where it says `No such file or directory`)

```
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _query_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Door
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _query_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Target
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  4%] Built target stereo_driver
[  7%] Built target camera_publisher
[ 10%] Built target stereo_publisher
[ 12%] Built target camera_subscriber
[ 12%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target stereo_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 12%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 12%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 12%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 12%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 12%] Built target stereo_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 12%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 12%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 12%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 12%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 12%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 12%] Built target stereo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 12%] Built target stereo_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 12%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 12%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 12%] Built target stereo_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 15%] Built target object_avoidance
[ 18%] Built target safe_mocap
[ 20%] Building CXX object rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.cpp.o
[ 22%] Built target connection_manager
[ 24%] Building CXX object rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/gps_publisher.dir/src/rqt_gcs/gps_publisher.cpp.o
[ 25%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 25%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 25%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 25%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 25%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 27%] Building CXX object rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/FIS/qfi_PFD.cpp.o
In file included from /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src/rqt_gcs/src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp:1:0:
/home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src/rqt_gcs/include/rqt_gcs/simple_control.h:33:29: fatal error: query_msgs/Door.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/build.make:208: recipe for target 'rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_control.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src/rqt_gcs/include/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.h:7:0,
                 from /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src/rqt_gcs/src/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.cpp:1:
/home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src/rqt_gcs/include/rqt_gcs/simple_control.h:33:29: fatal error: query_msgs/Door.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/build.make:184: recipe for target 'rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/src/rqt_gcs/simple_gcs.cpp.o] Error 1
[ 27%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 27%] Built target mavros_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 27%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 27%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 27%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 27%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 27%] Built target mavros_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 27%] Built target mavros_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 27%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[ 27%] Built target mavros_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 27%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 27%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
[ 27%] Built target mavros_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 27%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2160: recipe for target 'rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rqt_gcs/CMakeFiles/rqt_gcs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 27%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 27%] Built target bond_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Linking CXX executable /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/devel/lib/rqt_gcs/gps_publisher
[ 28%] Built target gps_publisher
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Base path: /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot
Source space: /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/src
Build space: /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/build
Devel space: /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/devel
Install space: /home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/karanvir/Documents/lcar-bot/build"
####
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235635/message-files-not-being-generated-properly-with-catkin_make/) by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-31**:
Please include the relevant `CMakeLists.txt` files in your question (without all the boilerplate comments), as well as the `package.xml` files. Without those it's going to be hard to provide pointers.

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-05-31**:
I've updated the description with links to the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-05-31**:
Please also include the exact error message in your question.

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-05-31**:
Sorry about that, I've updated the description to include the compile output.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-31**:
It'd be really nice if you could just include all the console copy/pastes in your question proper. If the pastebins ever goes away, this question will become useless. Same for the github links.

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-05-31**:
Sure I can do that. I just thought the question would be too long with all that stuff in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `CMakeLists.txt` you have a library target `${PROJECT_NAME}` which compiles all source files into a library. But that target does not have a dependency on `${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-05-31**:
Right, I'm not sure how to go about adding a dependency for that target. I have already tried doing add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) but that generates an error saying `Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "rqt_gcs"`

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-05-31**:
You must add the dependency **after** the lines containing `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ...`.

**Comment by [kPanesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20725/kpanesar/) on 2016-05-31**:
Wow, that was it! I can now compile repeatedly without any issues. It all makes sense now. Thank you!